# Are fictional polytheistic games haram to play?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, game

Salam Alaykum.

On this website, there was a similar question, but I have more to add.

There are mythological games/fantasy games with elements of polytheism, specifically with playable 'gods/archons'. I don't exactly understand if it is haraam or makrooh? If it falls into doubtful stuff and has no clear ruling, could avoid any doubts make it not haram? if it's not considered shirk/kufr to play, then why would it be haram (if it is), given that players know it is all fiction and it doesn't affect their real-life beliefs?
If playing it is haram, is avoiding the plot, playable 'gods', and statues alright to make it playable?

If anyone answers, please state your sources.

Comment: You could take all questions on games and mark them as makrooh. Any details require an individual fatwa and we are not a fatwa site.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty funny question to come across tbh, but you yourself are not associating any of these statue offerings or gods with Allah. Even if they are called "gods" As long as they are not viewed as the omnipotent singular god that Allah is, I don't think they can be considered as shirk.

It's just a game anyway right? Killing is also haram but many Muslims play COD or other FPS games. You could even say hitting someone with a red shell in mario kart is haram because it's unecessary violence lol.

Answer (score 0):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. The main purpose of our life is to worship ALLAH (Glory Be To Him). Not to be involved in those things/elements which are against Him (Glory Be To Him).

> I did not create jinn and humans except to worship Me. (Surah 51 verse 56)

Now when it comes to playing games that are using characters that do shirk then it is haram. It is the same if you dressed up as a rabbi / priest and started playing role play games. You are encouraging and allowing those elements which are shirk to be used. Let me support my viewpoint with the following ahadith:

> The Messenger of ALLAH (may peace be upon him) said: Act against the polytheists, trim closely the moustache and grow beard. (Muslim in the chapter of purification)

> "The Messenger of ALLAH [SAW] said: 'Change gray hair but do not imitate the Jews.'" (Nasai)

> Ibn Umar reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Whoever imitates a people is one of them.” (Abu Dawud)

Furthermore, digital drawings / digital figures could not be considered allowed due to these ahadith below:

> "I heard the Messenger of ALLAH [SAW] say: 'The angels do not enter a house in which there is a dog or an image of an animate being.'" (Nasai)

> "The Messenger of ALLAH [SAW] said: 'Whoever makes an image will be commanded on the Day of Resurrection to breathe the soul into it but he will not be able to do so.'" (Nasai)

> Messenger of ALLAH (ﷺ) said: "Jibra'il came to me and said: "Indeed I had come to you last night, and nothing prevented me from entering upon you at the house you were in, except that there were images of men at the door of the house, and there was a curtain screen with imagines on it, and there was a dog in the house. So go and sever the head of the image that is at the door so that it will become like a tree stump, and go and cut the screen and make two throw-cushions to be sat upon, and go and expel the dog." So the Messenger of ALLAH (ﷺ) did so, and the dog was a puppy belonging to Al-Husain or Al-Hasan which was under his belongings, so he ordered him to expel it. (Tirmidhi)

With the above mentioned ahadith the picture maker who imitated the creation of ALLAH (Glory Be To HIM) will be punished. Now can you imagine you are now imitating a polytheist/shirk character(s) and playing those characters then what would happen to that person!

**Have a nice day!**

Answer (score -1):

I would not play it to be safe. Its popularity can spread to kids, so they might actually believe things against Islam.